# axios request returns garbled json response

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I'm setting up a new server with `Express`, and sending http request with axios in my local. However, the axios response of json is garbled. Below is try, my content-type of request in axios.

```
headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=shift-jis',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'accept-encoding': null,
      proxy: false,
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      responseEncoding: 'binary',
      gzip: true,
      encoding: null,
    },
```

---

```
axios.get(options.url, options).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return res.send(response.data);
  });
```

I wanna get encoded Json response by shift-jis like `こんにちは`、 but the actual out put is `���M���X`. The reason why the letter is garbled may be in the configuration of `Accept-Encoding`. But how can I set this precisely?

Answer (score 0):

- resolve

`const axios = require('axios').create({
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
});`

```
axios.get(options.url, options).then((response: any) => {
    const str = iconv.decode(response.data, 'shift-JIS');
    console.log(`${str.toString()}`);
    return res.send(`${str.toString()}`);
  });
```